# Add specific route for Custom Post Type (add/edit...)

Tags: custom-post-types, routing

Is there a way to add custom route for CPT on front end ?

Actually, I've a "project" custom post type.
I need an URL like : `mydomain.com/project/add` and `mydomain.com/project/edit` with 2 dedicated templates for frontend forms.

Comment: you can create custom URL with this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: `add_rewrite_endpoint()` might be simpler for simple endpoints like `/add` or `/edit`.